# volumetric specific heat of insulation

Tags: power, cables, insulation

Could anyone please be so kind and point me to a relevant lookup table please? I did some google searches but could not find anything. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sounds like something the CRC Handbook would have.

Comment: It is actually in iec 60853-2. Just realized this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned, [IEC 60853-2](http://webstore.iec.ch/webstore/webstore.nsf/Artnum_PK/17420) deals with it and the [The CRC Handbook of Chemistry & Physics](http://www.hbcpnetbase.com/) does too. (And now the question is answered.)

Comment: So as I understand it your answer consists of two comments by others, one of them being OP?

Comment: @stevenvh Yes, to have the question not showing up as unanswered anymore. What does "OP" mean?

Comment: Original poster or original post. It will still show as unanswered if no answers are upvoted.